# Retorno de SQL em PHP converte acentuação para '?'

Tags: php, html, oracle, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou com um problema de *encode*, o meu retorno do Banco *Oracle* está fazendo os acentos em `?` alguém consegui me ajudar?
Detalhe preciso converter na variável não só no *Browser*, porque vou usar para um outro select.

```
       $sqlIn = "SELECT  distinct(LOCALIDADE_NOME) , COUNT(LOCALIDADE_NOME) FROM TBL_TA
            INNER JOIN TBL_TA_EQUIPAMENTO ON CODIGO=AEQ_TA WHERE TQA_ORIGEM IN ($listaIn)
            GROUP BY LOCALIDADE_NOME";
    $RESP_QUERYa = oci_parse($SS, $sqlIn);
    oci_execute($RESP_QUERYa);
    $afetacaolista = new ArrayObject();
    while (($row = oci_fetch_array($RESP_QUERYa, OCI_BOTH)) != false) {
        $afetacao = new afetacaoBean();
        echo $teste = utf8_encode($row['LOCALIDADE_NOME']) . "<br>";
        }
```

A Saida é:

```
RIBEIR?O PIRES 
VARZEA PAULISTA 
FRANCO DA ROCHA 
S?O PAULO 
JUNDIAI 
FRANCISCO MORATO
```

Já tentei varias coisas como :

```
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
    mb_http_output("iso-8859-1");
    ob_start("mb_output_handler");
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1", true);
```

Não Tenho como mudar a configuração do Banco nem de Tabelas.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%c3%bavida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8)

Comment: Fiz a Edição para não duplicar e o problema permanece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi pode ser o próprio encode da conexão com o Oracle.
Você pode tentar forçar a codificação na própria conexão dessa forma:

```
$conn = oci_connect( $username, $pass, $conn_string, 'UTF8' );
```