# Caracteres estranhos ao receber conteúdo do contact form

Tags: php

Form simples para envio de e-mail para a caixa de entrada do usuário, mas ao receber, os caracteres com acentos chegam distorcidos.

Exemplo: A palavra Codificação chega como "codificaÃ§Ã£o" no inbox. Não sei se o problema está na form ou no código.

PHP do form: https://codeshare.io/jGzQ9

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%c3%bavida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8)

Comment: veja se seu html está configurado o utf-8 e a lang, caso isso acontece no php também verifica isso por la.
'<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>'
'<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />'
ou você pode colocar diretamente no form '<form accept-charset="utf-8" ...>'

Comment: Todos os atributos supracitados já estão no meu HTML, ainda adicionei a propriedade no form; mas o erro persiste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tudo bem?!

Você precisa adicionar um **header** (*cabeçalho*) de encoding para a função **mail()**.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "email@host.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";

$headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $headers); or die("Error!");

echo "Obrigado! Entraremos em contato em breve.";
header( "refresh:5;url=index.html");
?>
```

Dê uma olhada na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php) do PHP para entender melhor a função **mail()**.

Comment: Obrigado, tanto os headers quanto a lida na documentação foi de grande valia. Acabei incrementando uma confirmação de envio com statement if/else básico. Tudo certinho por aqui.

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudá-lo.