# A base de dados não reconhece texto com caracteres especiais mesmo em UTF-8

Tags: php, html, utf-8

Já fiz muitas mudanças ao código e já pesquisei por vários sites e nada resolveu o meu problema!

Código HTML:

```
<div class="w3-container w3-padding-32" id="about">
<h3 class="w3-border-bottom w3-border-light-grey w3-padding-16">Sobre o site</h3>
<p>
    <?php
            $sql_sobre = "SELECT sobre_home FROM campos";
            $sql_sobrequery = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_sobre) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql_sobrequery);
            $decoded = utf8_encode($row[0]);
            echo $decoded;
    ?>
</p><div id="edicao" hidden><form method="POST" action="confirmarEdicao.php"><textarea class="textboxEditar" name="edicaoSobreHome"><?php echo $decoded ?></textarea> <input class="buttonEditar" type="submit" value="Confirmar"></form></div>
```

Código PHP:

```
    session_start();
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "aeac";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " .  mysqli_connect_error);
    }
    else{
      if (isset($_POST['edicaoSobreHome'])){
      $editar = $_POST['edicaoSobreHome'];
      $editar_encoded = utf8_encode($editar);
      $query = "UPDATE campos SET sobre_home = '$editar_encoded'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }
  }
```

O objetivo deste div é editar o texto no próprio site através de uma textarea escondida que aparece após clicar num botão com uma função em JS.

O meu problema aqui é que ao inserir caracteres especiais como letras com acentos, o texto na base de dados não reconhece os caracteres e retorna texto como o seguinte:

```
  "pode encontrar informaÃÂ§ÃÂ£o sobre as"
```

Comment: Como ta o cabeçalho do seu html?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Qual o charset da tabela no banco?

Comment: utf8_spanish_ci

Comment: Caro(a) RedCandy não use UTF8_DECODE OU UTF8_ENCODE, siga as instruções: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só remover o `utf8_encode` no update e do select.

Coloca na conexão do banco `mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")` para definir o charset do mysqli

```
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
  mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
```

```
      $editar = $_POST['edicaoSobreHome'];
      $editar_encoded = utf8_encode($editar);  //<-- remover essa linha
      $query = "UPDATE campos SET sobre_home = '$editar'"; //<-- aqui $editar

      var_dump($query); //<-- aqui tem que estar correto
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93059/discussion-on-answer-by-leonardo-barros-a-base-de-dados-nao-reconhece-texto-com)

Answer (score -1):

$pdf->load_html(utf8_decode($html)); 
Retire do código o "utf8_decode" e deixe desta forma---->>>>>>>>  $pdf->load_html($html);

Depois vai pegar caracteres especiais a vontade.