# Problema com acentuação no retorno do PHP para o Data Tables

Tags: php, mysql, json, jquery-datatables

Olá.
Estou realizando um consulta ao banco de dados, com php e mysql, e retorno o resultado dessa consulta para o DataTables (em forma de JSON) que lista esse resultado em uma tabela no meu HTML.

O problema é que estou tendo problema com **acentuação** na hora de listar o resultado no HTML.

Já tentei de tudo para formatar esses dados e não consegui. O que dificulta mais é que não tenho acesso ao retorno desses dados no JavaScript, pois ele é feito automaticamente com a biblioteca Data Tables.

Alguém poderia me ajudar.

**Segue abaixo o código:**

```html
<?php

session_start();
require_once("../../conexao/conexao-com-banco.php");

$departamento_usuario_logado = $_SESSION["departamento-usuario"];
$usuario_logado = $_SESSION["nome"];
$administrador = $_SESSION["administrador"];
$supervisor = $_SESSION["supervisor"];


//Receber a requisão da pesquisa 
$requestData = $_REQUEST;

$empresa_origem = !empty($_POST["empresa_origem"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'empresa_origem', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";
$departamento = !empty($_POST["departamento"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'departamento', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";
$funcionario = !empty($_POST["responsavel"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'responsavel', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";
$cod_empresa = !empty($_POST["cod"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cod', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";
$empresa = !empty($_POST["empresa"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'empresa', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";
$atividade = !empty($_POST["atividade"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'atividade', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";
$data_inicio = !empty($_POST["data_inicio"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data_inicio', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";
$data_fim = !empty($_POST["data_fim"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data_fim', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";


//Indice da coluna na tabela visualizar resultado => nome da coluna no banco de dados
$columns = array( 
 0 => 'responsavel',
 1 => 'empresas',
 2 =>'tipo_atividade', 
 3 => 'dt_vencimento',
 4 => 'enviado_por',
 5 => 'data_upload',
 6 => 'codigo'
);


if($data_inicio == "" || $data_fim == "")
{
 $query = ""; 
}
else
{
 $query = " AND a.dt_vencimento BETWEEN '$data_inicio' AND '$data_fim'" ;
}

//Obtendo registros de número total sem qualquer pesquisa
$contadorderegistros ="

SELECT
a.tipo_atividade,a.dt_vencimento, b.enviado_por, b.data_upload, b.codigo
FROM
tbl_atividades AS a
INNER JOIN 
tbl_arquivos AS b
ON
a.codigo = b.codigo_atividade
WHERE
a.departamento like '%$departamento%' AND a.responsavel like '%$funcionario%' AND a.cod like '%$cod_empresa%' AND a.empresas like '%$empresa%' AND a.tipo_atividade like '%$atividade%' AND a.empresa_origem like '%$empresa_origem%' '$query'";
 


/*
if(!empty($classificacao))
 $contadorderegistros.= " and classificacao = '$classificacao'";
if(!empty($descricao))
 $contadorderegistros.= " and descricao = '$descricao'";
*/

$resultado_arquiv = mysqli_query($conecta, $contadorderegistros);
$qnt_linhas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_arquiv);


//Obter os dados a serem apresentados
$dadosparapreenchimento = "
SELECT
a.responsavel,a.empresas,a.tipo_atividade,a.dt_vencimento,b.enviado_por, b.data_upload, b.codigo
FROM
tbl_atividades AS a
INNER JOIN 
tbl_arquivos AS b
ON
a.codigo = b.codigo_atividade 
WHERE
a.departamento like '%$departamento%' AND a.responsavel like '%$funcionario%' AND a.cod like '%$cod_empresa%' AND a.empresas like '%$empresa%' AND a.tipo_atividade like '%$atividade%' AND a.empresa_origem like '%$empresa_origem%' '$query'";

//echo $contadorderegistros;

//echo $dadosparapreenchimento;

if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {   // se houver um parâmetro de pesquisa, $requestData['search']['value'] contém o parâmetro de pesquisa
    $dadosparapreenchimento.=" and a.responsavel LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%'";
 $dadosparapreenchimento.=" or a.empresas LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%'";
 $dadosparapreenchimento.=" or a.tipo_atividade LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
 $dadosparapreenchimento.=" or a.dt_vencimento LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%'";
 $dadosparapreenchimento.=" or b.enviado_por LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%'";
 $dadosparapreenchimento.=" or b.data_upload LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%'";

 }


$resultado_arquivos = mysqli_query($conecta, $dadosparapreenchimento);
$totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_arquivos);

//Ordenar o resultado
$dadosparapreenchimento .= " ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";

//ACIMA, COMENTAMOS PARA COLOCAR O ORDER BY COM O NOSSO CRITÉRIO, QUE É A DATA DE UPLOAD (QUE ESTÁ NA QUERY ABAIXO)
//$dadosparapreenchimento .= " ORDER BY b.data_upload desc" . " LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']." " ;


$resultado_arquivos = mysqli_query($conecta, $dadosparapreenchimento);


// Ler e criar o array de dados
$dados = array();
while( $row_arquivo = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_arquivos) ) {  
 $dado = array(); 
 $dado[] = utf8_encode($row_arquivo["responsavel"]);
 $dado[] =  utf8_encode(substr($row_arquivo["empresas"],0,40));
 $dado[] =  utf8_encode($row_arquivo["tipo_atividade"]);
 $dado[] =  date("m-Y", strtotime($row_arquivo["dt_vencimento"]));  //Importante usar o utf8 em campos que vão conter acento pois dara erro no JSON
 $dado[] = utf8_encode($row_arquivo["enviado_por"]);
 $dado[] = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row_arquivo["data_upload"]));
 $dado[] = "<a class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' target='_blank' href=exibir-arquivo.php?codigo=" . $row_arquivo['codigo'] . "><i class='fas fa-cloud-download-alt'></i></a>";
 $dados[] = $dado;
}

//Cria o array de informações a serem retornadas para o Javascript
$json_data = array(
 "draw" => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),//para cada requisição é enviado um número como parâmetro
 "recordsTotal" => intval( $qnt_linhas ),  //Quantidade de registros que há no banco de dados
 "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), //Total de registros quando houver pesquisa
 "data" => $dados   //Array de dados completo dos dados retornados da tabela 
);




echo json_encode($json_data);  //enviar dados como formato json

?>
```

**SAÍDA NO HTML**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.
Não consegui entender o por quê, mas utilizando o utf8_encode() abraçando o utf8_decode(), que abraça os dados vindos do banco, deu certo.

Se alguém souber o motivo de ter dado certo, é só comentar aqui.

**Vejam como ficou a parte do código alterada:**

```html
<?php

  // Ler e criar o array de dados
$dados = array();
while( $row_arquivo = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_arquivos) ) {  
 $dado = array(); 
 $dado[] = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($row_arquivo["departamento"]));   //Importante usar o utf8 em campos que vão conter acento pois dara erro no JSON
 $dado[] = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($row_arquivo["cod"]));
 $dado[] = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($row_arquivo["empresas"]));
 $dado[] = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($row_arquivo["tributacao"]));
 $dado[] = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($row_arquivo["responsavel"]));
 $dado[] = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($row_arquivo["tipo_atividade"]));
 $dados[] = $dado;
}

?>
```

Comment: Tem algo de muito errado, pq não tem sentido ter quer usar ut8_decode e em seguida utf8_encode novamente, recomendo que leia isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635, trabalhar com CODECs tem que ter muito cuidado e fazer passo a passo e configurar o charset em tudo e salvar os arquivos .php e .js, se houver, com o codec certo.