# Caracteres especiais retornando em Json no PHP

Tags: php, json, utf-8

Fiz uma "api" para retornar os dados em formato json, no entanto, os registro que contém acento, está exibindo caracteres especiais.

Vejam meu código, o que eu poderia fazer, tem algum comando que posso adicionar?

Ja tentei colocar no json_encode alguns parametros, mas não deu certo.

Por favor preciso muito desta ajuda! Ja pesquisei bastante antes de vir aqui.

O php do meu servidor ja esta na versão 7

```
      <?php
    
    header('Content-type: application/json');

   require_once('dbConnect.php');

    mysqli_set_charset($conn, $charset);

    $response = array();

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT codigo, estado FROM estados");

   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   
   mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $codigo, $estado);
 
 if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {
   while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
     array_push($response, array("codigo" => $codigo,"estado" => $estado));
   }

    echo json_encode($response);
    } else {

       echo json_encode($response);

    }
?>
```

Os dados estão assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

Consegui uma solução, para quem estiver com o mesmo problema. Utilizei isto:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT codigo, estado FROM estados");
$linhas=mysqli_num_rows($sql); 


if( $linhas > 0 ) {
    while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
      //  $vetor[]= array_map('utf8_encode', $resultado); 
        $vetor[] =$resultado;
}    
    //Passando vetor em forma de json
    
    echo   json_encode($vetor);
} 
else
{
    
    $array = array(
        "codigo" => "0",
        "estado" => "vazio"
    );

    $vetor[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $array); 

    echo   json_encode($vetor);

 }
```

Comment: Imagina se você tiver 1 milhão de resultados e ter que  usar  array_map, mais pog que solução hehe. Recomendo o post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43193/4800