# Qual a diferença entre o php 5.6 e o php 7.3 em termos de codificação? Por que o php 7.3 afeta os caracteres do site?

Tags: php, utf-8

Estou há dias tentando atualizar a versão do php do meu site, mas, quando passo para o php 7.3, os caracteres ficam estranhos. Eu já vi perguntas semelhantes aqui, mas ninguém explica por que uma versão deixa os caracteres "bagunçados" e a outra versão (5.6) mantém tudo correto. Já vi alguém responder que nada mudou, mas claramente não é verdade, pois o problema só acontece quando muda de uma versão para outra, permanecendo todo o resto do site como sempre foi. Eu não quero alterar nada no meu banco de dados. Eu só quero saber o que mudou, em termos de codificação, para que esse problema aconteça. Talvez assim eu possa achar uma solução sem precisar mexer no banco de dados. Um detalhe interessante é que, quando fiz os testes de compatibilidade no Laragon, tudo funcionou perfeitamente, mas no meu servidor (Hostgator) deu esse problema.

Comment: Muito provavelmente é no seu Apache ou Nginx que a configuração esta causando os problemas, talvez você usa-se utf-8 por padrão e agora usa iso-8859-1 (não intencionalmente), ou ao contrário. Também pode ser a conexão do banco que você configurou indevidamente, leia um passo a passo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635, seguindo esse passo a passo provavelmente vai notar uma ou mais faltas de configs em seu projeto, se ainda tiver dificuldade basta [edit] a sua pergunta e fornecer um [mcve] (é muito importante ser bem simples e que reproduza o problema sem precisar de dependências)

Comment: Recomendo que leia: [Votos para fechar perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635) - Se conseguir fornecer o tal [mcve], que é regra minima de qualidade do site então poderemos analisar o seu problema e ajuda-lo. Recomendo também que leia: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/3635)

Comment: A conversa ficou improdutiva e os comentários em excesso deletados. Para questionamentos sobre o funcionamento do site utililze o site [meta], mas antes queira ler a documentação do site para evitar fechamentos lá também.